# Selecionar e exibir dados de a partir de uma posição na tabela do banco de dados

Tags: php

Estou precisando criar duas tabelas na mesma pagina onde na primeira terá  apenas um cliente, no caso, o primeiro da lista e na segunda os demais clientes, o problema é que quando listo a segunda tabela, o primeiro cliente também aparece, e eu preciso que a segunda tabela lista-se a partir do segundo cliente, pois quando o cliente da primeira é atendido a pagina recarrega e o primeiro de baixo sobe, assim sucessivamente.

O que eu tentei:

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'conexao.php';
$conexao = conexao::getInstance();
    $sql = 'SELECT id_agenda, hr_agendamento ,nome_cliente ,realizado FROM agenda
    WHERE nome_cliente = "nome_cliente "   and realizado ="N"  
     limit 1
    ';
    $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
    $stm->execute();
    $clientes = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$conexao2 = conexao::getInstance();
    $sql = 'SELECT id_agenda, hr_agendamento ,nome_cliente ,realizado FROM agenda
    WHERE nome_cliente = "nome_cliente "   and realizado ="N"  
     limit 3
    ';
    $stm = $conexao2->prepare($sql);
    $stm->execute();
    $clientes2 = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

?>
```

Como estão ficando as tabelas:

```
TABELA1
ID HORARIO CLIENTE REALIZADO
1  07:00    MARIA   NAO
TABELA2
ID HORARIO CLIENTE REALIZADO
1  07:00    MARIA   NAO
2  07:00    JOAO    NAO
3  07:00    CARLOS  NAO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `LIMIT` para fazer esse tipo de coisa também, veja como a query ficaria:

```
$sql = 'SELECT id_agenda, hr_agendamento, nome_cliente, realizado FROM agenda WHERE nome_cliente="nome_cliente" AND realizado="N" LIMIT 1, 3';
```

- O que significa `LIMIT 1, 3`?

A query irá selecionar a partir do elemento 1(começa do 0) e exibir ao máximo 3 elementos.

E o `OFFSET` também funciona da mesma forma:

```
$sql = 'SELECT id_agenda, hr_agendamento, nome_cliente, realizado FROM agenda WHERE nome_cliente="nome_cliente" AND realizado="N" LIMIT 3 OFFSET 1';
```

---

**Obs:** Peguei a query de sua pergunta para me basear, mas possivelmente ela está errada, visando que você está comparando uma coluna com o string "nome_cliente" e não com variáveis.

Veja como ficaria a comparação com uma variável:

```
$sql = "SELECT id_agenda, hr_agendamento, nome_cliente, realizado FROM agenda WHERE nome_cliente='$nome_cliente' AND realizado='N' LIMIT 1, 3";
```

E caso a variável esteja vindo no método post:

```
$sql = "SELECT id_agenda, hr_agendamento, nome_cliente, realizado FROM agenda WHERE nome_cliente='{$_POST['nome_cliente']}' AND realizado='N' LIMIT 1, 3";
```